# TensorFlow - always getting an AUC value of 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, roc, auc

I'm having an issue finding the AUC value in TensorFlow. I did the following to find the AUC:

```
auc,update_op = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_auc(predictions=y_pred_class,labels=y_true_class,curve='ROC')
```

Then, I did the following:

```
session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    session.run(tf.initialize_local_variables())
    auc_value, _ = session.run([auc,update_op], feed_dict=feed_dict_validate)
```

The code runs, but always getting the value `0`. What might I be doing wrong?

Is it correct to pass the classes of the prediction and the correct labels in `tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_auc`?

**EDIT**

You can get the full code from, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7n1jj9i4qcplgad/AAC98pXFNm-CBgmCGb1X17cFa?dl=1).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, and confusingly, [`tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_auc()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/metrics/streaming_auc) takes different parameters than [`tf.confusion_matrix()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/confusion_matrix) for example. You should *not* pass the class labels to this one, unlike for [`tf.confusion_matrix()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/confusion_matrix).

Here `predictions` should be the probability of each class (the value you get `y_pred_class` from with [`tf.argmax()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argmax)...).

Also labels should be in the one_hot format, furthermore in a boolean Tensor. (You can simply cast it to boolean, 0 will become false, 1 true.)

Looking at your code, a further problem is that you have to run the AUC `update_op` for each batch you run so that the AUC can accumulate the data. On the other hand, once you're done with a certain amount, you need to *reset* the internal variables of the AUC to zero so that further calculations, like AUC for validation, or the next training batch don't include the previous data. For this to happen, you need to be able to fish out those variables among all variables, therefore I've put this in a variable scope I'm calling "AUC". Putting this all together, a few parts where I've changed the code (will attach the full running, tested code for reference at the bottom):

Where the auc is defined (note, I've switched to the current version, [`tf.metrics.auc()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/auc) from the deprecated one in contrib):

```
with tf.variable_scope( "AUC" ):
    auc, auc_update_op = tf.metrics.auc( predictions=y_pred, labels=y_true, curve = 'ROC' )
auc_variables = [ v for v in tf.local_variables() if v.name.startswith( "AUC" ) ]
auc_reset_op = tf.initialize_variables( auc_variables )
```

The `show_progress()` function (note some formatting changes in the `msg = ...` line, those are not strictly necessary but reflect my taste only):

```
def show_progress(epoch, feed_dict_train, feed_dict_validate, val_loss):
    acc, auc_value = session.run([ accuracy, auc_update_op ], feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
    session.run( auc_reset_op )
    val_acc, val_auc_value = session.run([ accuracy, auc_update_op ], feed_dict=feed_dict_validate)
    session.run( auc_reset_op )
    msg = 'Training Epoch {} --- Tr Acc: {:>6.1%}, Tr AUC: {:>6.1%}, Val Acc: {:>6.1%}, Val AUC: {:>6.1%}, Val Loss: {:.3f}'
    print(msg.format(epoch + 1, acc, auc_value, val_acc, val_auc_value, val_loss))
```

And finally, in the `train()` function, note the inserted `auc_update_op`:

```
session.run( [ optimizer, auc_update_op ], feed_dict=feed_dict_tr)
```

Also, put session initialization at the end, just as "best practice", this is not strictly necessary:

```
with tf.Session() as session:
    #session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    # need to init local variables for internal auc calculations
    init = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
    session.run( init ) 
    train( num_iteration=10000 )
```

With this, the output is:

> Training Epoch 1 --- Tr Acc:  51.6%, Tr AUC:  51.0%, Val Acc:  46.1%, Val AUC:  46.1%, Val Loss: 4.893
>   Training Epoch 2 --- Tr Acc:  53.9%, Tr AUC:  53.0%, Val Acc:  53.5%, Val AUC:  55.3%, Val Loss: 0.691
>   Training Epoch 3 --- Tr Acc:  65.6%, Tr AUC:  63.9%, Val Acc:  65.2%, Val AUC:  69.0%, Val Loss: 0.647
>   Training Epoch 4 --- Tr Acc:  71.1%, Tr AUC:  71.6%, Val Acc:  68.0%, Val AUC:  74.8%, Val Loss: 0.586
>   Training Epoch 6 --- Tr Acc:  73.0%, Tr AUC:  76.8%, Val Acc:  69.5%, Val AUC:  75.9%, Val Loss: 0.588
>   Training Epoch 7 --- Tr Acc:  77.3%, Tr AUC:  82.4%, Val Acc:  73.8%, Val AUC:  77.7%, Val Loss: 0.563
>   Training Epoch 8 --- Tr Acc:  81.2%, Tr AUC:  87.0%, Val Acc:  78.9%, Val AUC:  85.2%, Val Loss: 0.475
>   Training Epoch 9 --- Tr Acc:  83.6%, Tr AUC:  90.9%, Val Acc:  75.0%, Val AUC:  83.5%, Val Loss: 0.517
>   Training Epoch 11 --- Tr Acc:  91.8%, Tr AUC:  94.3%, Val Acc:  73.0%, Val AUC:  81.4%, Val Loss: 0.646
>   (see more in attached `train.html` or `train.ipynb` below)

---

Data:
[Data is on Kaggle, from the Dogs vs. Cats competition (train.zip)](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/data)

Runnable tested main code (please note you need to adapt the data paths in the code to your specific setup and the batch size to your hardware capacity) in three formats:
[train.ipynb](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hah0mpYRS182TZ5xb1VvTkxoGM2-WU2K)  [train.html](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aSMbSuyOL4Exm0HiCihpmd7CTStSqpMn)  [train.py](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hox5DQ_ylKLI2cfDRoNMg9B9A6H-AGWv)

Required (imported) file, place it in the same folder as `train`:
[dataset.py](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iT6LpWitDdrC-pHqBL2LrpQK-DKpMoSj)

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I'm actually a bit new to this, and appreciate if you can provide a simple example on your thoughts?

Comment: For casting to boolean, would that be made for the "labels" only, or also for the "predictions"?

Comment: If I do "y_true_cls = tf.cast(y_true_cls, tf.bool)", I get this error: "Input 'y' of 'Equal' Op has type bool that does not match type int64 of argument 'x'."

Comment: Do it like this: `y_true_bool = tf.equal( y_true_cls, 1 )`

Comment: Added actual code suggestion to my answer as requested in your comment, based on looking up your question from yesterday.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications. Yes, I'm using the code you mentioned in the link. I'm still having AUC = 0, any thoughts why that might be?

Comment: Does you network work okay otherwise? Do you get some normal accuracy values? Zero might be a legitimate AUC value in case you have a model collapse, for example. You should also print `y_pred` and `y_true` and see if you feed good data to the auc calculation. Otherwise I'd need much more info to debug this, like your whole code I could run on my comp, including data.

Comment: Yes, I get normal accuracy values. Sure, I have added a link to the code in the edit to my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks so much for your nice answer and great efforts. I tried running your code on the Kaggle dataset and another dataset, but keep getting "assert batch_size <= self._num_examples". Any ideas on that?

Comment: Batch size is too big. I've changed it to 256 for my machine. Change it back to 100.

Comment: Oh yes, got it. In the two directories "cats" and "dogs", I had 100 images in each. So, when I set the batch size to "20" for instance it works! Thanks so much really for your kind efforts, prompt replies, and great answer. Appreciate it! Accepted your answer!

Comment: Just two quick questions. When running the code, I noticed that the epochs move a 1,4,7,.... How can we have the results epoch-by-epoch (1,2,3,...). Also, I noticed that the AUC value always "increases" through the epochs, unlike the accuracy for instance that increases and decreases. Is that normal? Or there might be an issue causing the value to always increase? Thanks

Comment: Epochs: yeah, sorry, I've also changed the code that calls the show_progress to show after 100 batches, change it back to show by epoch. AUC increases: the network is learning, that's why :) accuracy is a worse measure, because basically it's a binarized version of AUC. Take the measurement more frequently, that will give you some ups and downs probably. But if you take a look at my output above, you can see that the validation AUC actually did decrease for the 8th and 9th report line.